# How to fix the inconsistent line spacing in TikZ box?

Tags: tikz-styles

The spacing between the lines looks inconsistent in the Ti*k*Z box. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bookman}
\geometry{paperheight=77.45cm,paperwidth=101.6cm,margin=4mm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{almond}{rgb}{0.94, 0.87, 0.8}
\begin{document}
\centering
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=almond,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=40pt, inner ysep=40pt, xshift=5cm]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=white, text=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [mybox,anchor=north west,font=\fontsize{70}{0}\selectfont] (box) at 
([shift={(1cm,-5cm)}]current page.north west){%
\begin{minipage}{0.40\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt,font=\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont] at (box.north 
west) {WARNING};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=almond,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=40pt, inner ysep=40pt, xshift=-1cm]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=white, text=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [mybox,anchor=north east,font=\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont] (box) at 
([shift={(-5cm,-5cm)}]current page.north east){%
\begin{minipage}{0.40\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt,font=\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont] at (box.north 
west) {BLENDING INFORMATION};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is the intention of `\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont` ? which (in any context) is more or less forcing inconsistent spacing, since it requests a large font set on 0pt (!!!!) baseline

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, please use `\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=black, fill=almond,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=40pt, inner ysep=40pt, xshift=5cm},
fancytitle/.style={fill=white, text=black}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paperheight=77.45cm,paperwidth=101.6cm,
            margin=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{almond}{rgb}{0.94, 0.87, 0.8}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\tikzset{mybox/.style = {draw=black, fill=almond,
        rectangle, rounded corners, 
        inner sep=40pt, text width=#1},
    fancytitle/.style = {fill=white, text=black}
        }
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
    node distance=5cm and 5cm]
\node [mybox=0.4\textwidth,
       font=\fontsize{70}{77}\selectfont,
       below right=of current page.north west] (box-left)  {\\ \lipsum[1-1]};
\node[fancytitle, 
      font=\fontsize{60}{66}\selectfont,
      below right] at (box-left.north west) {WARNING};
%
\node [mybox=0.4\linewidth,
       font=\fontsize{60}{66}\selectfont,
       below left=of current page.north east] (box-right)  {\\ \lipsum[1-1]};
\node[fancytitle, 
      font=\fontsize{60}{66}\selectfont,
      below right] at (box-right.north west) {BLENDING INFORMATION};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- In above MWE are considered comments below question.
- better result you will obtain, if  use the same font size in all nodes. In this case selection of its size can be moved to the `box` style definition:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paperheight=77.45cm,paperwidth=101.6cm,
            margin=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{almond}{rgb}{0.94, 0.87, 0.8}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\tikzset{mybox/.style = {draw=black, fill=almond,
        rectangle, rounded corners, 
        inner sep=40pt, text width=#1,
        font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont,},
    fancytitle/.style = {fill=white, text=black,
        font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont}
        }
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
    node distance=5cm and 5cm]
\node [mybox=0.4\textwidth,
       below right=of current page.north west] (box-left)  {\lipsum[1-1]};
\node[fancytitle, 
      right] at (box-left.north west) {WARNING};
%
\node [mybox=0.4\linewidth,
       below left=of current page.north east] (box-right)  {\lipsum[1-1]};
\node[fancytitle, 
      right] at (box-right.north west) {BLENDING INFORMATION};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]